# pySerial multiple access on a port

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

I have a caller id device which can handle up to 4 lines and it communicates with computer using usb serial port. With pySerial I've written below code:

```
import serial
from time import sleep

s = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial', 115200)

def event_stream():

    # Modified code from thread reading the serial port
    while True:
        data = s.read()  # Wait forever for anything
        # print tdata
        sleep(1)  # Sleep (or inWaiting() doesn't give the correct value)
        data_left = s.inWaiting()  # Get the number of characters ready to be read
        data += s.read(data_left)  # Do the read and combine it with the first character
        if data:
            if 'CallerID' in data:
                start = data.find(':CallerID:') + 10
                end = data.find(' ', start)
                caller_id = data[start:end]

                start = data.rfind('L', 0, start - 10) + 1
                end = data.find(':', start)
                line = int(data[start:end])

                yield 'event: discovery\ndata: %s\n\n' % json.dumps(dict(line=line, caller_id=caller_id))
            elif 'RingsCount' in data:
                start = data.find(':RingsCount:') + 12
                end = data.find(' ', start)
                ring_count = int(data[start:end])

                start = data.rfind('L', 0, start - 12) + 1
                end = data.find(':', start)
                line = int(data[start:end])
                yield 'event: ringing\ndata: %s\n\n' % json.dumps(dict(line=line, count=ring_count))

for data in event_stream():
    print data
```

When somebody calls to line 1 or 2 or ... this code catches caller id and everything works perfectly but when line 1 and line 2 called at the same time pySerial raises this exception and can't catch caller ids.

```
SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

Is there any way to handle all 4 lines at the same time?

Comment: I'd say that this is more a problem with your device than with pySerial.

Comment: I find your double-read shenanigans troublesome. Why don't you sleep in a loop until inWaiting() returns something positive, then read that and process.

Comment: I'd recommend using a proper I/O/Async framework here like [circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits) or [Twisted](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted)

Comment: @JamesMills I'm using a multithread flask application with server sent events. When some one calls caller I push an event to connected user browser.

Comment: That doesn't change the problem, you can run twisted in a thread if you want.